# Adding <param> to <object>

Tags: javascript, activex

In my javascript code, I'm creating an `<object>` like so:

```
var myObject = document.createElement('object');
```

Then, I to add some parameters to this object, so that these are reflected in my html.

I can do it like this, but after adding more and more paremeters, this code gets really messy and repetitive.

```
var param1 = document.createElement('param');
param.setAttribute('name', 'myName');
param.setAttribute('value', 'myValue');
myObject.appendChild(param1);
```

Is there a better way to create an  and add parameters to this object?

If it makes any difference, this is an activeX control object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could put that code into an `addParameters` function that takes an object and uses a `for in` loop to add all of the properties in the object.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to add properties

### 1

```
param1.name=myName;
```

### 2

```
param1[name]=myName;
```

And u can check if the property exists in the object by looping through it using `for in` and ensure that you use `hasProperty` to restrict it to objects own properties.

Answer (score 0):

There's an exciting buffet of options open to you:

```
elem.id = 'NewId';
elem.value = 'NewValue';//etc...
elem.style.width = '100%';
```

Or, if you're only creating 1 object:

```
elem = '<div id="Foo" class="bar blackBlock andSomeOtherClass">InnerText or innerHTML go here</div>';
```

Which, in most cases is even faster than creating it manually... :)

If not, here's a little function I use from time to time:

```
function createAssign(elem,attr)
{
    var i;
    elem = (typeof elem === 'object' ? elem : document.createElement(elem));
    if (typeof attr !== 'object')
    {
        return elem;
    }
    for (i in attr)
    {
        if (attr.hasOwnProperty(i))
        {
            elem[i] = (typeof attr[i] === 'object' ? createAssign(elem[i],attr[i]) : attr[i]);
        }
    }
    if (this !== window && this.appendChild)
    {
        this.appendChild(elem);
        return true;
    }
    return elem;
}
var el = createAssign('div',{id:'Foo',innerHTML:'bar',style:{width:'100%'}});
//or append directly:
createAssign.apply(document.body,['div',{id:'Foo',innerHTML:'bar',style:{width:'100%'}}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it

```
function addParams(obj, paramsObj){

  for(vals in paramsObj)
  {
     obj.setAttribute(vals, paramsObj[vals])
  }
}

var myObject = document.createElement('object');
var paramsObj = {
                  "value":"myValue"
                  "name":"myName" 
                };

addParams(myObject, paramsObj);
```

Comment: How would you deal with `paramsObj = {style:{width:'100%'}};`?